# Customize iterating over numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy, iterator

I'm using python 3.X and I want to create such iterator that will allow me to iterate a matrix from cell [N,0] to [0,N]

I don't want to use indices-magic so I tried `np.nditer` which is not enough for that.

```
a = np.matrix(np.random.randint(0,3,(3,3)))
>>>([[0, 0, 1],
    [1, 1, 2],
    [1, 2, 2]])
it = np.nditer(a, flags=['f_index'])
for i in range(a.size):
    print(it[0])
    it.iternext()
>>>0 0 1 1 1 2 1 2 2
```

I want to get the following :
1,2,2,1,1,2,0,0,1

Is it possible using iterators of some kind?

Comment: I'm puzzled why so many posters try to use `nditer`.  Is there something in the documentation that makes you think it's easier to use, or faster?  What's wrong with `indices-magic` (what ever that is)?

Answer (score 0):

```
In [29]: arr = np.array([[0,0,1],[1,1,2],[1,2,2]])                                                           
In [30]: arr[::-1,:]                                                                                         
Out[30]: 
array([[1, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 2],
       [0, 0, 1]])
In [31]: arr[::-1,:].ravel()                                                                                 
Out[31]: array([1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1])
```